# Default value of slider via python script

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to Blender and I'm jumping into the deep end with scripting. Is it possible to get the default value of a slider? For example, I'm after the anti-aliasing filter value.

```
# get current anti-alias setting
AA = bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size

# change anti alias value
x = 1.2
bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size = x

get the default value and revert back to it when finished
# AAdefault = bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size.default ???
bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size = AAdefault
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Get default value

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size = 2.0
print(bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size)
# >>> 2.0
default_value = bpy.context.scene.render.bl_rna.properties["filter_size"].default
print(default_value)
# >>> 1.5

# bpy.context.scene.render.filter_size = default_value
```